# Java script that show an ordered sequence of images each page refresh

Tags: javascript

I would like to transform this Javascript below that show randomly 3 images each page refresh, to **an ordered sequences of images**, for example first image1.jpg, second image2.jpg etc..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "image1.jpg";
image[1] = "image2.jpg";
image[2] = "image3.jpg";

var hasard = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length);

$('#css-id span img').attr('src', 'http://url..' + image[hasard]);

});

</script>
```

there is a way? MANY THANKS!

Comment: you store the index of the currently displayed image in `localStorage` - next time you load the page, you read from `localStorage` ... increment (and wrap around), display the indexed image, and store the new index in localStorage

Comment: Vanilla JS or jQuery?

Comment: It's normal javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all three images in order, then what you need to do is select the 3 image (I hope there are three elements for showing 3 images) element using the query selector.

As you have not posted the html you want to manipulate, we can only assume its something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="css-id">
    <span>
      <img src="" alt="">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function($){

  var image = new Array ();
  image[0] = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495894307-93143fc57155?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60";
  image[1] = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624377149599-65e4b8cd6fa0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60";
  image[2] = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624129126429-0775cd4ea284?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60";

    image.forEach((i, index) => {
      $('#css-id span img').eq(index).attr('src', i);
    });

  });
</script>
</html>
```

This will give you the desired result, you can change the query selector as per your actual html.

Comment: Many thanks DeadpooL ! unfortunately you are writing to a javascript incompetent :-( ..I don't think it is three different elements, but the same: specifically it is a module of a Wordpress theme, the theme is Divi, I have inserted a single "image module".. would it change anything?